# Fetch remote JSON ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

In Ionic 5 I need help to fetch remote data from a server. Basically i try to get data in json format from a remote REST service.
I have have created a service provider and I use httpClient get method to fetch json like this:

```
getCategories() {

        return this.http.get(this.env.API_URL + 'prova-cat')
            .subscribe(data => {
                console.log('data:' + data);
              }, error => {
                console.log(error);
             });
        }
```

then in provider I use in ngOnInit()

```
let categories = this.categorieService()
```

Where I'm wrong? If I look on the console I get Observable data

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example. [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the values inside the subscription. And it is better to subscribe inside the component instead of the service. That way you proceed further only after the asynchronous data has been received from the backend. Try the following:

Service

```js
getCategories(): observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.env.API_URL + 'prova-cat');
}
```

Component

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private categories: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.categorieService.getCategories().subscribe(data => {
      console.log('data:' + data);
      this.categories = data;         // <-- assign value here
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```